# Android Fragment switching from navigation drawer causes app to quit

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the slider menu displayview method as:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();

                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    String tag = fragment.getTag(); // instance method of a to get a tag

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(tag);
                    ft.commit();

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                    drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    drawerListView.setSelection(position);
                    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
                } else {
                    // error in creating fragment
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
                }
            }
```

I have a fragment called home_fragment whose code behind is `HomeFragment.java`

When I click on this fragment first it works fine, but on clicking next from the siding menu at index 0 I get an error as:

```
Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

This is where I'm having error:

```
case OP_REMOVE: {
                    Fragment f = op.fragment;
                    f.mNextAnim = exitAnim;
                    mManager.removeFragment(f, transition, transitionStyle);
                } break;
```

This code is present in BackStackRecord.java

Comment: Where are you using mNextAnim?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `container.removeAllViewsInLayout()`.

The `FragmentManager` will handle all the view manipulation on the container when you call `FragmentTransaction.replace()`, including removing the current fragment view.  You are probably getting an error because the `FragmentManager` expects a fragment's view to be in the container, but you've removed it.

All you need is this:

```
        private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // set fragment to other nav target
                    fragment = ...
                    break;
                .
                .
                .
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                drawerListView.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
```

Also I noticed you are using `getFragmentManager()`.  Please check your class imports and make sure that you have the right call.

- If `HomeFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`, use `getFragmentManager()`.
- If `HomeFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Now I used this: `fragment = new HomeFragment();

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        String tag = fragment.getTag(); // instance method of a to get a tag

                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
                        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
                        ft.commit();` same error.

Comment: You don't need that either.  One single call to `replace()` will handle removing the current fragment and adding the new fragment,  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this, upvoting it for explaining the logic to me, will accept once I'm through.